# Objective-c: Fast Fuzzy Search Match

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, search, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

Does anyone know of a fast implementation of fuzzy search matching for Objective-c?  (levenshtein-distance algorithm).

I found this: https://github.com/thetron/StringScore/blob/master/NSString%2BScore.m - but it's unfortunately pretty slow. I need to compare this to a about 200 strings, and it's continuous - per new keystroke typed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If NSString+Score does what you want but is too slow, you could start by speeding it up. Lines 23 to 28 in `-scoreAgainst:fuzziness:options:` are setup code that only need to be done once, not on every of the 200 compares. So pull that code out into a setup method and measure again.

Edit:

As an exercise, I [forked StringScore](https://github.com/w-m/StringScore), extracted the setup code and did minimal changes to get some performance improvement, then measured it. I used 1000 random words, grouped them in three each (e.g. "disrupted dot drinking"). For each of these groups I did the setup (as told in this original answer) and then compared the string to all of the 1000 groups. This takes around 11 seconds on my Core 2 Duo.

So comparing one word to 1000 takes about 11 ms. Now you only need 1 to 200, so it will be probably well under 10 ms. That should work for you?

(By the way, nearly half the time is still spent in rangeOfString: finding a single character; this can probably done much much faster, but I didn't want to get in the details of the algorithm.)

Comment: Thanks, this does improve it considerably, however it's still too slow.

Comment: @Wesley it baffles me that it's too slow for you, so I measured it. See edit of the post.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but you were right. I had another observer that was also being triggered at the same time that was the culprit. Nevertheless, your optimizations are worthwhile. Thank you!

Comment: @w.m Thanks for the tip! Did you want to open a pull request on that change so I can merge it into master? The port was done very quickly, and not really measured very carefully for performance, I'd love to get some updates on there.

Comment: @theTRON my current hack is pretty bad API-wise, as it exposes so many internals - but I'll get back to you with a better solution as soon as I can spare some time

Comment: @w-m have you spared some time? :)

Comment: I have not and I probably won't in the future as I'm not even using StringScore. Maybe someone will step in, someone who is properly motivated? There seems to be no lack of interest, and a couple forks on Github on MIT license to get you going.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the algorithm you're referring implemented in Objective-C

Is there a reason you are not using the built in functionality of NSPredicate with CoreData.  I have found this very fast searching more than 200 strings.

For example, given an NSString *searchText and a fetchedResultsController

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];

self.filteredListContents = [[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

You can also use an NSPredicate on an NSArray, which I assume you have tried and found to be too slow.

From the apple documentation

```
NSMutableArray *array =
[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Nick", @"Ben", @"Adam", @"Melissa", nil];

NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'a'"];

NSArray *beginWithB = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
// beginWithB contains { @"Adam" }.

NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'e'"];

[array filterUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
// array now contains { @"Nick", @"Ben", @"Melissa" }
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Comment: Thanks, since fuzzy matching is too slow, I'm looking for something that can find matches that contain all words. So if if I'm looking for "Stack Overflow", matched objects would be "Stack Overflow" and "Overflow Stack". I guess this could be accomplished with NSPredicate if I take apart all words and try it for each word separately. I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Wesley but that would be just [NSSet setWithArray:[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] isEqual:otherSet]

Comment: @w.m Well, not entirely, it should also match "Overflow match stack", etc. Anyway, looks like I have to do either a regex search on each word or a predicate search on each word.

Comment: You can do some fairly powerful matching with predicates @Wesley Here's an example from live code NSPredicate * mechPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id CONTAINS[cd] %@ || product.brand.heading CONTAINS[cd] %@ || product.category.name CONTAINS[cd] %@ && count = 1", searchText,searchText,searchText];